# Can I travel to Russia and China with a passport whose cover is fading?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, china, russia

My passport's cover's text is fading: the name of the country is still readable but the coat of arms has almost disappeared.

The rest of the passport is fairly okay--you can see I bring it around quite a lot, but it's not wet or broken and the personal information page is completely legible.

I have visa-free access to both **Russia** and **China**, so I wonder if they will be extra strict on me because of this. Noteworthy, I reside in **Germany**. Also, I will be entering by **train** to both countries.

Any (bad?) experiences?

Comment: I don't think Chinese immigration would care at all; they usually are quite lax. I can't speak for the Russians.

Comment: @Paul That question's answer says it varies from country to country (therefore country specific questions make sense), then it mentions some countries that aren't Russia or China...

Comment: @user568458 The answer will be purely opinion based regardless. `so I wonder if they will be extra strict on me because of this`

Comment: @xuq01 at some of the land borders especially in the west, China's border security is far from lax - but my experience was that despite them searching electronic devices for potentially illegal photos and trying to confiscate books and maps that depicted Taiwan as an independent nation, they didn't care at all about my passport's tatty and faded cover. Was many years ago now though

Comment: @Paul Only if you consider official statements of national policy and / or direct personal experience to be "opinion"...!